# HTML Correct way to wrap labels and fields

Tags: html

What's the correct way to wrap fieldset and labels in HTML?

E.g.

```
<label> First name </label> 
<input type="text" name="firstname">

<label> Nick Name </label> 
<input type="text" name="Nickname">

<label> Surname </label> 
<input type="text" name="Surname">

<label> Favourite Color </label> 
<input type="text" name="favourite-color">

<label> Favourite TV Show </label> 
<input type="text" name="favourite-tv-show">

<label> Favourite Food </label> 
<input type="text" name="favourite-food">
```

I want to wrap each label and input in a HTML tag, so they are easier to arrange into a grid.

e.g.

```
    <div>
<label> First name </label> 
<input type="text" name="firstname">
    </div>

    <div>
<label> Nick Name </label> 
<input type="text" name="Nickname">
    </div>
```

Is [fieldset](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_fieldset.asp)  the correct tag? I wasn't sure if you were supposed to use that for individual label and input pairs or for groups of them (e.g. all the Name inputs would be in a fieldset tag and all the favourites would be in another fieldset tag).

I know I can use a DIV (as in my second example), but I am not sure if that is the best tag.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are several correct ways. You can wrap them in a `div`, or in a `span`, or inside cells of a table row. Other approaches are possible, too, but less natural. A [`fieldset`](http://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-label-element) element is for a *group* of controls and associated labels. A group with a single control is formally correct, but rather pointless. Neither `div` nor `span` has any meaning assigned to it, apart from constituting a block level or inline element, respectively. But since you probably want each control to start on a new line, `div` makes things simpler, as it has such rendering by default. A `table` element constitutes a grid of elements and is therefore a natural choice, because a collection of controls and associated labels logically forms a grid.

In any case, note that `label` elements as used in the example are rather pointless and provide no functional advantages. They should have `for` attributes that associate each of them with its control, by its `id` attribute.

Answer (score 3):

```
<div>
  <label> First name </label>
  <input type="text" name="firstname">
</div>
<div>
  <label> Nick Name </label>
  <input type="text" name="Nickname">
</div>
<div>
  <label> Surname </label>
  <input type="text" name="Surname">
</div>
<div>
  <label> Favourite Color </label>
  <input type="text" name="favourite-color">
</div>
<div>
  <label> Favourite TV Show </label>
  <input type="text" name="favourite-tv-show">
</div>
<div>
  <label> Favourite Food </label>
  <input type="text" name="favourite-food">
</div>
```

If more styles are required, you can use additional css styles for that

```
div{
 display: table-row;
}
label,input{
 display:table-cell;
}
```

Comment: I need each label/input pair wrapped in a tag. I have updated my question to make this clearer.

Comment: so to confirm it's better to use a DIV instead of a fieldset.

Comment: the formatting of code just hurt my eyes and I had to correct it. Now that it's readable, one can clearly see that your labels are useless, they need 'for' attributes and inputs need 'id' attributes that labels can point to

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can use `fieldset`, in form it´s correct tag. (you don´t need that, regarding question edit).

**Here are other options:**

You can use whatever, not only `fieldset` (eg. `div`). If you want to wrap all fields (and labels) together, use one `fieldset`. If you need to wrap each single pair, use `div`.

But, maybe you don´t need to wrap these pairs, only rearrange your HTML. What about this code?

```
<label> 
    First name
    <input type="text" name="firstname">
</label>

<label> 
    Nick Name
    <input type="text" name="Nickname">
</label>

<label> 
    Surname  
    <input type="text" name="Surname">
</label>

<label> 
    Favourite Color
    <input type="text" name="favourite-color">
</label>

<label> 
    Favourite TV Show 
    <input type="text" name="favourite-tv-show">
</label>

<label> 
    Favourite Food 
    <input type="text" name="favourite-food"
</label>
```

You can make a grid using a `float` on `label`s (for example, if you want to have two pairs in one row), etc.

Comment: And then if I need to style the labels differently would I wrap them in spans?

Comment: For example. I don´t know what exactly you need, how it should look. But yes, you can wrap label text into span if you need to work with (youcan style directly label if you need color, etc., if you need to set size of label text, you can set width to label and inputs and float inputs right. For example)

Answer (score 1):

What you have is correct.  The label tag allows users to click on it's text to toggle the control.  See: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp

Fieldset just allows you to group like inputs.

You can use an HTML table to style your labels and inputs to look nice, along with css.

```
<fieldset>
<label> First name </label> 
<input type="text" name="firstname">

<label> Nick Name </label> 
<input type="text" name="Nickname">

<label> Surname </label> 
<input type="text" name="Surname">

<label> Favourite Color </label> 
<input type="text" name="favourite-color">

<label> Favourite TV Show </label> 
<input type="text" name="favourite-tv-show">

<label> Favourite Food </label> 
<input type="text" name="favourite-food">
</fieldset>
```

You can style it like so (add within the  tags:

```
<style>
fieldset {
  padding: 1em;
  font:80%/1 sans-serif;
  }
label {
  float:left;
  width:25%;
  margin-right:0.5em;
  padding-top:0.2em;
  text-align:right;
  font-weight:bold;
  }
</style>
```

Comment: So is <label> only to be used for radio buttons? Also, I don't think tables would be the best tag for styling.

Comment: No, you can use a label for any of the input elements.  I've edited my post with an example of how you can style the fieldset to look nice

Comment: But I need each pair (of labels and inputs) to be wrapped in a tag, as I am going to put them into a grid. I know I can use a DIV but I am not sure if that is the best tag.

Comment: Yes, I would create a parent div container for the grid itself, then put each label/input combination into a div and float it to the left.  The divs will automatically overflow to the next line once they hit the parent div's side.